# "O sea después"

Tags: gramática, estilo

> Chateé con mis amigos virtuales 3 horas y  o sea, 3 horas después fui de compras con mi esposa.

What's another alternative for ' o sea' ?

Comment: That use of "o sea" is wrong. Many spanish people use "o sea" on that way, but it is still wrong. Consider it the fruit of poor expression, like when in English some people abuse of the "like" word. Correct examples of "o sea" can be read on @serfe answer.

Comment: Yeah it is kinda wrong, 'o sea' is mainly used in actual spoken conversations, and rarely on a written statement, it does look weird as others have pointed. During spoken coversations you will hear it often though, although it doesn't really mean a lot, quite as much as you will hear 'so like..' in the US and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that context, it is just a catchy phrase. You should omit it, it is kinda "posh" :)

Comment: Could i say it in a colloquial way?

Comment: You can say it, of course! but I suggest you not to say that...

Answer (score 3):

In that case "o sea" is not relevant, it has no meaning. To go further I woudln't use it there, it sounds weird for me.

But in other case you can use "es decir", "así que" o "por lo tanto" instead of "o sea".

> Esta noche viene uno más a cenar, o sea, al final somos 5.
>
> Esta noche viene uno más a cenar, es decir, al final somos 5.
>
> Esta noche viene uno más a cenar, por lo tanto, al final somos 5.
>
> No creo que eso sea posible, o sea que no voy a hacerte caso.
>
> No creo que eso sea posible, así que no voy a hacerte caso.